# sp_BlitzCache: Plan Cache 100% in last 4 hours

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitz, sp-blitzfirst

This is a [re-post of my question here](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/141253/plan-cache-100-plans-created-in-last-4-hours.html)

`BlitzCache` suggests there may be memory pressure, but I think there is another problem. I just don't know what that problem is!

`sp_blitzFirst @ExpertMode = 1;` says there isn't a problem, but

```
SELECT MIN(creation_time) FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats;
```

says nothing is lasting longer than an hour.

[image]

Comment: Try running `sp_BlitzFirst @SinceStartup = 1` and show us your wait stats

Comment: The screen cap is fine. Your server seems really bored! What are you concerned about?

Comment: Try posting the contents of sp_Blitz in your question too: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/10/updated-first-responder-kit-sp_blitz-markdown-output-sp_blitzindex-statistics-checks/

Comment: Your original question said you're seeing recompiles of all your queries. If that's happening, for each row in the sp_BlitzCache results, values for the CreatedAt and LastExecution columns should match. Is that true?

Also, what metrics in sp_BlitzCache are you seeing that suggest memory pressure?

Finally, is this issue of plan cache turnover impacting performance, or is it just interesting? (Curious if symptoms can point to something else.)

Comment: @Erik: none of the plans are being re-used; isn't this a problem that SQL is spending it's time recompiling for no good reason?

Comment: @Brent; my reputation won't allow more than one image in a post @Doug; the final comment from BliztCache said "100% of plans were in last 4 hours... may be memory pressure"

Comment: @brent:: EXEC dbo.sp_Blitz [at]OutputType = 'markdown', [at]CheckServerInfo = 1 ... Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_Blitz, Line 5685
Divide by zero error encountered.

Comment: @DaSiHu Hmm, something's up there - try it with CheckServerInfo = 0, but that divide-by-zero makes it sound like you've got no memory in the server.

Comment: @Brent "No memory" - meaning memory is all being used up / VM under pressure & paging out? Could that explain why the plan cache is not being reused? Am i worried over nothing??

Comment: @DaSiHu your best bet is to follow the suggestions I've already posted. Thanks!